# DialogFlow not recognizing audio inputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I am using DialogFlow chatbot to detect text and audio inputs ,text is working fine, but audio doesn't,
I am reading audio files I generate (.mp3 and .wav) and read it in nodejs and sending it but there is no response, I get an empty intent, its not even logged in DialogFlow History, but when I provide it with a sample audio from DialogFlow it works fine,
Here is my code I, am following the documentation provided by DialogFlow:

```
const sessionId = uuid.v4();

  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
    projectId,
    keyFilename,
  });

  const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
  const inputAudio = await readFile('myfilepath.mp3');
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      audioConfig: {
        audioEncoding: 'AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16',
        sampleRateHertz: 16000,
        languageCode: 'en-US',
      },
    },
    inputAudio,
  };
  const [response] = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);

  console.log('Detected intent:');
  console.log(response);

  const result = response.queryResult;

  console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
  console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
```

The response is always

```
{
  responseId: '',
  queryResult: {
    fulfillmentMessages: [],
    outputContexts: [],
    queryText: '',
    speechRecognitionConfidence: 0,
    action: '',
    parameters: null,
    allRequiredParamsPresent: false,
    fulfillmentText: '',
    webhookSource: '',
    webhookPayload: null,
    intent: null,
    intentDetectionConfidence: 0,
    diagnosticInfo: null,
    languageCode: 'en-US',
    sentimentAnalysisResult: null
  },
  webhookStatus: null,
  outputAudio: <Buffer >,
  outputAudioConfig: null
}
```

Is there a specific way to generate audio file I have to follow or what?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is due to the encoding and the sample rate from your audio files.

I was able to replicate the scenario and get your `response` output using the [samples](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/tree/master/samples#detect-intent-audio) from [nodejs-dialogflow](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow), in particular the `detect.js` [one](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/master/samples/detect.js), with an MP3 file running the sample like this:

```
node detect audio resources/book_a_room.mp3 -r 16000
```

When looking at the supported encodings on the sample running:

```
node detect audio -help
```

We can see that the options available are the following:

```
  -e, --encoding    The encoding of the input audio.
              [choices: "AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16", "AUDIO_ENCODING_FLAC", "AUDIO_ENCODING_MULAW", "AUDIO_ENCODING_AMR",
                  "AUDIO_ENCODING_AMR_WB", "AUDIO_ENCODING_OGG_OPUS", "AUDIO_ENCODING_SPEEX_WITH_HEADER_BYTE"] [default:
                                                                                             "AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16"]
```

These options can also be seen on the Dialogflow API [reference](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryInput#audioencoding) for `AudioEncoding`. From there we can conclude that **MP3 is not a supported encoding**, and that's why you get that `response` output.

Also when looking at the Dialogflow API [reference](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryInput#audioencoding) you can see the following:

> ... Refer to the Cloud Speech API [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics) for more details.

Looking into that documentation and going to the encoding [section](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding), you can see that:

> Note: Speech-to-Text supports WAV files with LINEAR16 or MULAW encoded
> audio.

So going back to the encoding options from the Dialogflow API we can see that for WAV files, the ones you could use are:

- AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16
- AUDIO_ENCODING_MULAW

It's important to notice that `AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16` option is set by default.

Thus, you could use **WAV files with 1 channel with the proper sample rate according to the one that your WAV file has (e.g. 44100)**, and then you'll get the desired response. For example:

```
node detect audio resources/book_a_room_1ch_16Khz.wav -r 16000
```

Or

```
node detect audio resources/book-a-room_1ch_44.1Khz.wav -r 44100
```

Otherwise, you'll get error messages like the following:

```
{ Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Must use single channel (mono) audio, but WAV header indicates 2 channels.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus ...
```

And

```
{ Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: sample_rate_hertz (16000) in RecognitionConfig must either be omitted or match the value in the WAV header ( 44100).
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus ...
```